# Using phonegap and html5 video tag: caveats?

Tags: html, video, cordova

I am planning to build a JavaScript/HTML5 app, and wrap it with phonegap to be installed on an android tablet.

In it, I want to show a video file.

Is it just a matter of creating an index.html file, and putting a mymov.ogv file in the same directory, and then using:

```
<video src="mymov.ogv"...>
```

and it will work on Android?

I have read about some problems with this, but my quest got me confused.

What are the caveats, if any?

PS: the video should be packaged within phonegap, such that the video is shown when the app is not connected to wifi. So it's a local file.

PPS: Since it's for internal use, I am able to choose a particular modern android version (if that makes any difference). There is no need to support old android versions whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

According to this resource: http://caniuse.com/ogv There is not support for ogv format in Android.  Remember that Phonegap applications are just display in a rapped browser window-- So if the browser doesn't support it, you can't use it.  Whether the video is on-board the device or streamed, doesn't matter.

You can certainly embed with the  tag, but you might want to use the associated Javascript API to provide some control over the video.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, we can change the ogv format. What format for instance is widely supported? Do you happen to know?

Comment: MP4 is likely your best bet.